# Is $C(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R})$ seperable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

During this pandemic I was self studying metric spaces and I came across this problem as exercise in a book.

> Let $\mathbb{Z}$ (Integers)  be a discrete metric space where each set is open and $C(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R})$ be a metric space  of all continous bounded functions from integers to real numbers under the norm $||f|| = sup{f}$. Show that $C(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R})$ is not separable.

I know that each function from integers to real number is continous since each inverse image is subset of integers which is open.

I know that if we want show a metric space is not seperable then for every countable subset of metric space there is a point which is not limit point of that subset. I am not able to solve this problem with this approach. Is there any other approach? I'm not getting how can we use countability of subset to show it is not dense.

Comment: What topology are you using for $C(\Bbb Z,\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Hint: Mimic [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: @Brian M. Scott It was with respect to supremum norm, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

For each subset $A$ of  $\mathbb N$ define $f_A(n)=1$ if $ n \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\|f_A-f_B\|=1$ whenever $A \neq B$. Since there are uncoutbaly many subsets of $\mathbb N$ it follows that $C(\mathbb Z, \mathbb R)$ is not separable.

[Suppose there is a countable dense set $(f_k)$. Then the ball of radius $1/2$ around $f_A$ must contain $f_k$  for at least one $k$. Call this $f_{k(A)}$. Verify that $ A \to k(A)$ is a one-to-one function from the family of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ into the set of positive integers. This is a contradiction].